# How to identify out of boundaries and assign a value in R

Tags: r

I am working over a list of tables (called `list_list`) with a simple function I wrote using `sapply`. I want to take the 4th element of each table and create a vector containing all these 4th values.

```
vect<-sapply(list_list, function(x) y<-x[[4]])
```

It happens that the first table (and some more) has just 3 elements.

Hence, when I run my function I get the  message:

`Error in x[[4]] : subscript out of bounds`.

I changed my function (called `fun_fun`) to assign `0` if a table made up of just three elements occurs, like this:

```
fun_fun<-function (x){
 y<-ifelse (x[[4]]==FALSE, 0, x[[4]])
}
```

and then `sapply(list_list, fun_fun)`

but it doesn't work.

Here an example:

My list of tables is like the following:

```
$`Sep 2015`

1  2  3 
16 24  4 

$`Aug 2015`

  1   2   3   4 
 60 208 235  93 

$`Jul 2015`

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
  76  405 1090 1883 2129 1584  760  221   34    2
```

where you can see the first three tables, named "Sep 2015", "Aug 2015" and "Jul 2015".
I'm interested in getting all the fourth elements, here you can see that "Sep 2015" has just 3, and get a vector like the following: `0, 93, 1883`.

Any suggestions? How can identify and "use" the occurrence of an `out of bounds` case?
Thanks a lot, U

Comment: It would help to have a reproducible example. Are you working with list elements?  If not, try `[` instead.  It will return NA.  Example: `x <- 1:3; x[[4]] # Error in x[[4]] : subscript out of bounds; x[4]; # [1] NA`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt help, I just inserted an example. U

Comment: Why do you want `0` there?  Wouldn't `NA` make more sense because there really is no value there? Look at `sapply(list_list, "[", 4)` and see what you think.

Comment: Actually `sapply(list_list, function(x) unname(x)[4])` would be a little bit cleaner.

Comment: May be I am not so much skilled to get your help, but if I try    fun_fun<-function (x){
  y<-ifelse (x[4]==FALSE, NA, x[[4]])
}
sapply(list_list, fun_fun)  I get  NA          93        1883 but the subscript changes like this: Sep 2015.NA  Aug 2015.4  Jul 2015.4 <code>

Comment: I'm saying don't even use `fun_fun` at all.  Just run the code from my comments exactly as it is.

Comment: It works. I'd like to understand why. However, 0 would be better than NAs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x[[4]]` doesn't exist, then `x[[4]] == FALSE` doesn't work. You can't check if something is false if it doesn't exist.

You can check for the length of the element:

```
list_list <- list('aug' = 1:3, 'sep' = 1:5) # testdata
sapply(list_list, function(x) return(ifelse(length(x) >= 4, x[[4]], 0)))
```

Comment: Cristal clear, wonderful. I've learned something today, thanx

Comment: You don't need `ifelse()` though since `length(x) >= 4` will always be a single logical value. A simple `if(length(x) >= 4) x[[4]] else 0` would do it and would be faster.

Comment: True. I tried to stay close to Umberto's code, so I decided to use ifelse(). According to the documentation on ifelse() a regular if else structure is indeed more efficient.